# MySQL Left Join and not equals

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I am messing up with MySQL Query... I want to take a table records which are not exist with some value in another table but I don't want using NOT IN operation. Then, I try to use LEFT JOIN to display unmatched data. However, It displays empty result:

tbl_comment

```
comment_id | comment_message
----------------------------
1_1        | some text1...
1_2        | some text2...
1_3        | some text3...
2_1        | some text4...
2_2        | some text5...
2_3        | some text6...
```

tbl_analysis

```
analysis_id | analysis_message_id
----------------------------
1.0.1       | 1_1
1.0.1       | 1_2
1.0.1       | 2_1
1.0.2       | 1_3
1.0.3       | 2_2
```

My Wrong Query (empty result):

```
SELECT comments.* ,
       analysis.*
FROM tbl_comment as comments

LEFT JOIN tbl_analysis as analysis

ON comments.comment_id = analysis.analysis_message_id

WHERE analysis.analysis_id != '1.0.1'
```

Suggested Result:
(find all the comments that the **analysis_id** is not equals to **1.0.1** or not exist in **tbl_analysis**)

```
  comment_id  | comment_message | analysis_id | analysis_message_id
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    1_3        | some text3...   | 1.0.2       | 1_3
    2_2        | some text5...   | 1.0.3       | 2_2
    2_3        | some text6...   | NULL        | NULL
```

Thanks for great help...

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: use right join if you want to show tbl_analysis unmatched rows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are performing a `LEFT JOIN` onto the `comments` table yet you have included a predicate on one of the columns in the `comments` table i.e. `WHERE analysis.analysis_id != '1.0.1'`. This will negate your `LEFT JOIN`. Try this instead

```
SELECT comments.* ,
       analysis.*
FROM tbl_comment as comments
LEFT JOIN tbl_analysis as analysis
ON comments.comment_id = analysis.analysis_message_id AND analysis.analysis_id != '1.0.1'
;
```

Comment: OK. Just leave off the `WHERE` clause if you want unmatched stuff too. Will edit my answer.

Comment: oops, It seems to work (sorry, I was mis-checking the result). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
SELECT comments.* , analysis.*
FROM tbl_comment as comments
LEFT JOIN tbl_analysis as analysis
ON comments.comment_id = analysis.analysis_message_id
WHERE analysis.analysis_id IS NULL
//IS NULL OR IS NOT NULL according to you requirement.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code may be it will work.

```
SELECT *

FROM tbl_comment as c

right JOIN tbl_analysis as a ON c.comment_id = a.analysis_message_id

WHERE a.analysis_id != '1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select alias is wrong. Try this:

```
SELECT comment.* ,
       analysis.*

FROM tbl_comment as comments

LEFT JOIN tbl_analysis as analysis ON comments.comment_id = analysis.analysis_message_id

WHERE analysis.analysis_id != '1.0.1'
```